# Prevent to create object twice

Tags: scala, functional-programming, kafka-producer-api

I have following code:

```
  type Request = EitherT[IO, Throwable, KkProducerRecordMetadata]

  def create(producer: => KkProducerCreator)
  : IO[Producer[String, String]]
  = IO {
    try {
      new KafkaProducer[String, String](properties(producer))
    } catch {
      case e: InstanceAlreadyExistsException => ???
    }

  }

  def send(producer: => IO[Producer[String, String]])
          (record: => KkProducerRecord)
  : Request = EitherT(for {
    p <- producer
    m <- IO {
      try {
        //If MaxBlockMs is not set,
        //then after 60s it will throw an exception
        val pr = new ProducerRecord[String, String](record.topic, record.key, record.value)
        val meta = p.send(pr).get()
        p.flush()

        Right(KkProducerRecordMetadata(meta.hasOffset,
          meta.hasTimestamp,
          meta.offset,
          meta.partition,
          meta.timestamp,
          meta.topic))
      } catch {
        case e: Exception => Left(e)
      }
    }
  } yield m)

  def close(producer: => IO[Producer[String, String]])
  : IO[Unit]
  = producer.map { p =>
    p.flush()
    p.close()
  }
```

The function `create` creates a kafka producer and wrapped into `IO` because it could produce side effect.

The function `send` will send the message to kafka and as you can see on the first argument, it expects a `producer`.

And I am using the function as following:

```
  //Creates a producer
  private val pSignIn: IO[Producer[String, String]] =
    KkProducer.create(KkProducerCreator(sys.env.get("KAFKA_SERVER").get,
      "AUTH-SIGNIN-PRODUCER",
      List(MaxBlockMsConfig(4000))))
```

and send message to kafka:

```
KkProducer.send(pSignIn)(KkProducerRecord(AuthTopology.SignInReqTopic,
        AuthTopology.SignInKey, a))
```

As you can see, every time when the `send` function get called, a new instance of producer will be created and then I get an exception:

```
javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: kafka.producer:type=app-info,id=AUTH-SIGNIN-PRODUCER
```

How to prevent, that the producer is getting to create twice in the functional way? 
I was thinking to create a map of producers and the id as key?
Would be `StateT` the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you are creating the producer once. Assign the producer instance to a `val` or a `lazy val` and then pass val to the functions.

Change the parameter of `send` and `close` function from call by name to normal parameter (call by value).

Call by name parameter is evaluated every time when referred by variable name there by creating producer for every `send` call.

Declare you `send` like below

```
def send(producer: IO[Producer[String, String]])(record: => KkProducerRecord)
```

Same applies to `close`

Example:

```
def foo(code: => Int) = code + code + 1

def bar(code: Int) = code + code + 1
```

#### Scala REPL

```
scala> :paste
// Entering paste mode (ctrl-D to finish)

def foo(code: => Int) = code + code + 1

def bar(code: Int) = code + code + 1


// Exiting paste mode, now interpreting.

foo: (code: => Int)Int
bar: (code: Int)Int

scala> foo({println("evaluated"); 1})
evaluated
evaluated
res1: Int = 3

scala> bar({println("evaluated"); 1})
evaluated
res2: Int = 3
```

Notice: In case of `foo` println block got evaluated twice unlike bar.

Comment: I thought `Call by name` will evaluated only once. It is not lazy evaluation?

Comment: @zero_coding code passed to call by name variable will remain unevaluated and will get eveluated every time the variable name is called

Comment: Does not work, still got the exeption: `javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: kafka.producer:type=app-info,id=AUTH-SIGNIN-PRODUCER`

Comment: @zero_coding call by name and `lazy val` are two different things

Comment: @zero_coding you are calling producer creation two more than once. Check ur code. or paste ur new code

Comment: @zero_coding capture the instance of the producer into `val` or `lazy val` and then pass the producer instance to the functions.

Comment: That is because of the `IO` monad. Every time the `IO` get called, it will evaluate stuff inside the `IO`.

Comment: @zero_coding `lazy val producer = IO {
    try {
      new KafkaProducer[String, String](properties(producer))
    } catch {
      case e: InstanceAlreadyExistsException => ???
    }`